# Update Partial View on a click

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new in dotnet core mvc. Help me to understand this.
Let's say I have a view page. In this page I have a partial view and passing a model data to that partial view. Suppose I have a button. when button click event happened I want to update the model data that was passed to the partial view.

```
 <form id="preference-form1">
       <partial name="Partial/_PreferenceFormOne" model="Model.EventDates" />
</form>
```

Can I passed new model data on that click event ? Can I update this without make any ajax call to the controller ?

Comment: Do you want to pass data partial view without the main view refresh or what ? Could you share more code to describe what you want ? How do you  update the model data  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try pass the data with query part,I tried in a minimal mvc proj as below:

Index View:

```
@model ViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<button id="btn1"> @Model?.Id</button>
<div id="partial">
<partial name="Partial" model="@Model?.anotherModel"/>
</div>



<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script >
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#partial").load("/Home/Partial?Id=3&Prop=xqxq")
    });
</script>
```

Partial View:

```
@model AnotherModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<a>@Model?.Id</a>

<a>@Model?.Prop</a>
```

Models:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int  Id { get; set; }
        public AnotherModel? anotherModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnotherModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Prop { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var vm = new ViewModel() { Id = 1, anotherModel = new AnotherModel() { Id = 2, Prop = "SomeProp" } };

            return View(vm);
        }

        public IActionResult Partial(AnotherModel anotherModel)
        {
            return View(anotherModel);
       }
```

Result:
[image]

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0) related with model binding to learn how to pass the data with key -value pairs